# Changing a read-only file

Tags: python, text

I need to change text documents. The way I've been doing it is making a new file, copying everything line by line from the old file and making changes on the way, then saving the new file as the old file's name. This becomes a problem when I only have read permission on the file. First I get OSErrno 30, not letting me delete the old file at the end of the writing. If I change my open command to 'r+', it simply says the file is not found. I don't have root access. Does anyone know of a workaround to this problem?

EDIT: Thanks for the responses. I guess that IS the intended behavior of a read-only file...

Comment: There is only one "workaround": If you don't have write access to your input file, write out your data under a different name (possibly in a different direction).

Comment: if you don't have permission, you can't change it.

Comment: You do realise, that not being able to make modifications is the intended behavior when not having permission to modify a file?

Comment: That would be a major security flaw if you somehow found a way to write/modify a read-only file

Comment: Permissions are there for a good reason. From a design perspective it would be no good for you to be able to change files that you did not have permission to alter. You can consider this to be a good thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, 
you are right,
you can only read
where you cannot write.

Comment: I vote to award the 'poet' badge. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297339/1907906